# How does FitBit manage to totally take over NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

The FitBit app just introduced its new NFC functionality and now, even though my app, and several other apps I have installed on my device are all registered (in the manifest) as NFC apps, Android no longer asks me which app I'd like to use and just goest straight to FitBit when I scan the NFC tag to my devices.

I'm curious what they could be doing to override the settings in the manifest.  Is there some way that they can be running a Service that dominates NFC and swallows all incoming NFC intents?

I'm hoping there's some way to undermine what they're doing cause currently, in effect, their app is malware that breaks the underlying basic NFC functionality on Android.

Answer (score 1):

A service cannot receive NFC intents, so that cannot be the cause of what you see. As far as I can tell, the FitBit app filters for NFC events with MIME type "text/plain". So if your NFC tag contains an NDEF text record, it will likely start FitBit or, if more apps are installed with the same intent filter for NFC and "text/plain", an app chooser is shown for the relevant apps.

Try scanning another tag with different content or change the content on your tag to a different type of NDEF message and see what happens.

Comment: Well, along with my app (which has a pretty lengthy list of NFC related items in the Manifest, I can post that if it would be useful) I'm running NFC Tag Info, which, when the FitBit app is not installed, always presents itself as an optional app when any NFC tag I have used (and I've tried various types encoded with various NDEF messages) is tapped. However, once FitBit is installed, NFCTagInfo no longer gets to play and FitBit is auto launched from the device's Home screen.  Could you please elaborate a bit more on what you would like me to do to prove this out?

Comment: What is not entirely clear to me is whether this happens with one specific NFC tag or several or all tags. It would be useful to check (e.g. with TagInfo) what the NDEF contents is of the tag(s).

Answer (score 1):

I have an app with a specific intent filter for one of its activities:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="duckapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

If a scan a tag with an URL starting with `duckapp://`, my app's activity is started directly even though I have other NFC apps such as TagInfo installed.

I don't know for sure. But it seems that if one activity has a more specific intent filter than all the other apps, it's directly started.

If anybody knows about a precise documentation of this mechanism, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: yeah... the odd thing is though that I have this (and a bunch of other) NFC definitions in my activity's manifest, so, I'm stumped as to why it's being superceded by FitBit, though I'm liking NFC Guy's thought about the specific mime type... maybe that's the key to this.

Comment: For details on intent filtering, read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs